# what are modules in programming (Android)

Tags: android, module

What are modules in programming? I have done some research and based on google's documentation:

> Modules provide a container for your app's source code, resource
> files, and app level settings, such as the module-level build file and
> Android manifest file. Each module can be independently built, tested,
> and debugged.

I didn't fully understand it. where do we use it? what's the example? can anyone give an explanation with a useful example?

Comment: anyone? nobody can tell? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't understand the google's documentation about modules but from other websites, modules are and can be pieces of a project. It means that a project can be divided into several modules to make the testing easy and carry some of the pressure built on the main UI module. Another use is that developers can add pre-built modules to their projects.